# Can I have ArangoDB 2.8 and ArangoDB 3 on the same server?

Tags: arangodb

I need to transfer a lot of databases from arango 2.8 to version 3.

Can I run them simultaneously, on the same machine, on different ports in order to export them and import them on the spot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the only way to run two versions of ArangoDB on the same machine would be to have a chroot with the other version, or run the second version in a docker environment.

There are files with the same locations in the 2.8 and 3.0 packages, hence the `arangodb3` packages conflict with with the `arangodb` version 2.x packages.

You can in debian/ubuntu use [DeBootstrap](https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap) to initialize a minimal `chroot` for ArangoDB; for Centos/Redhat etc. [yumbootstrap](https://github.com/dozzie/yumbootstrap) seems to provide a similar solution. As Nate already told you, you need to [configure the ports `arangod` binds to a different port](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/Manual/Administration/Configuration/Endpoint.html).

Using [docker](https://www.docker.com) you [can use our official ArangoDB image in the docker library](https://hub.docker.com/_/arangodb/). Since docker sets up virtual ips, you probably can use the same port - as long as you don't bind `0.0.0.0:8529` in the host system. Please pay attention to the `Persistent Data` chapter of the docker container manual and read on:

Once your migration is complete, you can install ArangoDB 3 in the host, and move the database directories over. You should take care that the chroot is on the same volume as your current `/var/lib/arangodb` directory, so moving is cheap.

Comment: Is there anything to prevent George from simply migrating via package management upgrade, in place?

Comment: Yes, you have to dump & re-import the packages. If you want to minimize the downtime, or try it out whether everything works out, you should try the approach.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend running Arangodump and Arangoimp. This simply exports entire collections to json files which can be rapidly imported. Details [here](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/Manual/Administration/Arangoimp.html). You can simply Arangodump your Arango 2.8 files, uninstall ArangoDB 2.8, install 3.0, and import them into Arango 3.0. I don't have any experience running two versions simultaneously, but unless they are containerized I would not recommend trying, as both versions, when locally installed, use files in a directory with the same name (`/usr/share/arangodb`).

Comment: Yes, I noticed that both start with "arangod" as a service name, that's why I asked. Unfortunately I don't use containers, not yet at least. I guess I will set up arango 3 In a new VM and try to import them there before I uninstall completely arango 2.8. Thanks.

Comment: You might also be interested in arangorestore